# University of Phoenix Salary Data

Tags: data-request, collegescorecard

I am skeptical about the College Scorecard data for University of Phoenix.
Why do all the campuses have the same median salary?

Comment: Could you give us a link?

Comment: @BarryCarter - probably https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/search/?&name=university%20of%20phoenix

Answer (score 3):

Many data elements, including earnings data, are available only for Title IV recipients, or students who receive federal grants and loans. The cohorts for these data elements are based on reporting at the individual level to the National Student Loan Data System (NSLDS), which is used to distribute federal aid.  Scorecard publishes these data at the aggregate 6-digit OPE ID institutional level (the variable name in Scorecard is: opeid6), which can be thought of as a main or central campus. In many cases, IPEDS institutions (with a unique UNITID), which can sometimes be thought of as branch campuses, share a common 6-digit OPE ID.  For these cases, all of the (branch) campuses mapping to the same (main) 6-digit OPE ID are  assigned the same (student-weighted) average outcome or median outcome for students across all branches of the institution for NSLDS and tax-data derived measures.